# fig.set_figheight and fig.set_figwidth not working

Tags: python, matplotlib

Why is this code not changing the size of the figure plotted?

```
   fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3)
   fig1.set_figheight = 30
   fig1.set_figwidth = 30
   x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
   for i in range(3):
       ax1[i].plot(x, x**i)
```

[This is what I am getting][[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2hgt.png)

Is there a way to make them bigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fig1.set_figheight = 30` assigns `30` to the `.set_figheight` attribute. While previously `fig1.set_figheight` was a method that could be used to change the height of the figure, from now on it is, well, simply `30`.

The solution is simple: *Use* the method instead of destroying it.

```
fig1.set_figheight(30)
```

Note that because you have overwritten the method you will need to restart the kernel, such that matplotlib can be reimported and the attribute is restored to its original state.